# Definition of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am new in probability theory and still have some difficulties to capture the definition of random variables.

- given repeated throws of dice will produce a sequence of random variables. A random variable being defined as a function on a measure space, the previous example could be modeled as being described with the aid of a single random variable: an outcome will be described by the (random) value of the function. But in fact it is not.
- given a sample of a population for which the distribution of the height of each individual is to be determined is again thought of as each individual being a random variable and you are not considering a single random variable to describe the process.

It looks like a random variable assumes only one value. Can somebody explain what could my misunderstanding be ? Thanks.

Comment: In the measure-theoretic framework, a random variable is a function on the sample space. Therefore given a value in the sample space, which might be called a "randomization parameter" and is traditionally denoted by $\omega$, you have a single real number (or vector, or whatever values the random variable takes). But $\omega$ is then randomly selected when we imagine actually performing the experiment. The value taken on by our random variable is also randomized in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Typically a random variable denotes a (real) number that is random. For example, let $X$ be the outcome of rolling a 6-sided die. Mathematically, we can model this by taking our probability space to be the unit interval and taking $X(\omega)$ to be the function
$$
X(\omega)=\lfloor 6\omega\rfloor+1.
$$
Then $\mathbb P(X=1)=\mathbb P(0\leq \omega<1/6)=1/6$, and similarly for the other values of $X$, so this truly models an unbiased die.

Now consider a sequence of $n$ dice rolls. Either we can consider each roll in isolation of the others, in which case we can use the same function $X(\omega)$ above to describe each roll, or we can consider the joint distribution of the dice rolls. Then the outcome of the experiment is a random vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in \mathbb R^n$. Thus we have a single random vector.

People also consider randomness in more general contexts, beyond just real numbers or real vectors. In this case it is common to use the term random element.

Answer (score 0):

The only confusion I'm seeing in your post regards terminology.

I've typically seen random *variables* used to refer to real-valued maps from a probability space, and random *vectors* to refer to vector-valued (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$) from a probability space. You can think of the realization of $n$ dice rolls as $n$ random variables (e.g. $X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega)$) or a single realization of a random vector (e.g. $f(\omega)=(X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega))$).